# converter getAsObject method not invoked

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, converters, selectonemenu

I have a `<h:selectOneMenu>`.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="LoanType" style="width: 180px; font-size: 12px;" value ="#{editLoan.currentLoanType}" converter="#{convertToLoanType}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{editLoan.loanTypeList}" var="parLoanType" itemValue="#{parLoanType}" itemLabel="#{parLoanType.loanTypename}"/>
    <f:ajax listener="#{editLoan.loanTypeChanged}" execute="@this"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

If user changes selection, then I would like to invoke a listener method. However, my converter's `getAsObject()` method is not invoked. Only `getAsString()` method is, so I'm getting `null` variable in the listener method.

Here is my converter class:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class ConvertToLoanType implements Converter {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "CrasmonClientPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        try{
            int id = Integer.parseInt(value);
            System.out.println("getting as object");
            return em.find(ParLoantype.class, id);

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        try{
            ParLoantype pa = (ParLoantype) value;
            return String.valueOf(pa.getLoanTypeid());

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is my backing bean bean class:

```
@Named(value = "editLoan")
@SessionScoped
public class EditLoan implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private LoanmainController lmainController;

    ParLoantype currentLoanType;
    LoanMain loanMain;
    List<LoanMain> allLoans;
    List<ParLoantype> loanTypeList;

    public EditLoan() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        currentLoanType = lmainController.findLoantype(1);
        this.allLoans = findLoansByParLoantype(currentLoanType);
        this.loanTypeList = lmainController.prepareAllParLoantype();   
    }

    public void loanTypeChanged(){
        System.out.println(this.currentLoanType.getLoanTypename());
        //this.allLoans = findLoansByParLoantype(currentLoanType);
    }

    public List<LoanMain> findLoansByParLoantype(ParLoantype type){
        return lmainController.findLoansByParLoanType(type.getLoanTypeid());
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in converter's method? Or is this just your naive observation of the absence of             `System.out.println("getting as object");`? Have you really excluded the possibility that `Integer#parseInt()` threw an exception?

Comment: Yes I did. It doesn't goes through method at all. But I solved it by putting 'required = "true"' in selectOneMenu component. I thought converter works after validation. So required means there are validation then converter does its job.

Comment: Hmm, this is unexpected. Which JSF impl/version are you using? Which `javax.faces.*` context params do you have in `web.xml`? By the way, converters runs before validators.

Answer (score 2):

Did you ensure putting `<p:selectOneMenu>` inside a `<h:form>`? This was my mistake when converter was not invoked.

Comment: yes I had the same problem and this was the problem thanks :)